# Is it possible to get Posts and Reposts by an organisation using LinkedIn Community API?

Tags: json, linkedin-api

I have made a query ( https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization... + the access token ) which retrieves the organisations posts. However the reposts that the organisation makes of employees blog posts from their personal accounts don't show up. Is there some thing I can add or do I have to make another query to get the reposts of employee blogs?

(https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization... + access token) was tried and I cant seem to find anything online to retrieve posts and reposts